# Python- print some rows to new file

Tags: python, csv

Newbie question.. 
I've got a massive (2M+ Row) csv file with 3 columns

```
Name : Metric 1 : Metric 2 
BOB :  1000 : 0
SUE :  1200 : 4
SAM : 1250 : 4
```

How can i output a new file that only has the full rows where metric 2 is NOT zero and still maintain the headers?

thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is:

1. Open the `csv` file and read the lines;
2. Scan the lines and see which line has the attributes you want;
3. Output these lines in a new `csv` file.

Here's a quick example:

```
inp = open('input.csv', 'r')
out = open('output.csv', 'w')
lines = inp.readlines()
inp.close()

out.write(lines[0])
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
    if i > 0:
        cells = line.split(',')
        if int(cells[2]):
            out.write(line)

out.close()
```

The above code will produce the output you want, like this:

```
INPUT.CSV:             ->  OUTPUT.CSV:

Name,Metric 1,Metric 2     Name,Metric 1,Metric 2
BOB :  1000 : 0        ->  SUE,1200,4
SUE,1200,4             ->  SAM,1250,4
SAM,1250,4
```

Answer (score 0):

Python's csv module has a DictReader object that would work well for this. I would read and write them on-the-fly, as holding large data sets in memory could be problematic later on.

You can check to see if your value in the desired column is 0. If not, write the line.

```
import csv

with open('mycsvinput.csv', 'r') as file_input, open('mycsvoutput.csv', 'w') as file_output:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(file_input)
    csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(file_output, fieldnames=csv_reader.fieldnames)

    csv_writer.writeheader()

    for line in csv_reader:
        if line['Metric 2'].strip() != '0':
            csv_writer.writerow(line)
```

Edit: if your rows in csv have whitespace padding on each value, you may want to strip it before checking for 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use csv module.

```
C:\Users\kvivek\Desktop>type test.csv
Name , Metric 1 , Metric 2
BOB ,  1000 , 0
SUE ,  1200 , 4
SAM , 1250 , 4
C:\Users\kvivek\Desktop>python
>>> import csv
>>> reader = csv.reader(open(r'C:\Users\kvivek\Desktop\test.csv'))
>>> for row in reader:
...   if '0' not in row[2] :
...      print row
...
['Name ', ' Metric 1 ', ' Metric 2 ']
['SUE ', '  1200 ', ' 4']
['SAM ', ' 1250 ', ' 4']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

A good data structure and data analysis library is pandas.
Let's say you have stored your data in a file called `a.txt`

```
import pandas
```

Read the file in Python (the columns are separated by a colon in your case):

```
table=pandas.read_csv("a.txt",sep=":")
```

Print to check what you got:

```
print(table)
  Name    Metric 1    Metric 2 
0  BOB         1000           0
1  SUE         1200           4
2  SAM         1250           4
```

Create a new dataframe that contains only the rows where '' Metric 2 ' is 0.

```
table2=table.loc[table[' Metric 2 '] == 0]
```

Print to check.

```
print(table2)
  Name    Metric 1    Metric 2 
0  BOB         1000           0
```

Export the filtered dataframe to a CSV file.

```
table2.csv("a.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

why do you need python for this? just use `head` and `grep`.

```
head -1 your.csv > result.csv 
grep -v ": 0$" your.csv >> result.csv  # since i can't see your exact format, you'll have to make sure that ": 0$" is right...
```

but if you insist on python, just do:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('your.csv', sep=':')
df[df['Metric 2'] != 0].to_csv('result.csv')
```